# Recently viewed product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, reports

I display 4 recently viewed product in my home page. If cache is disabled in back end then only it works fine, other wise all the system have same product.

How  can  i fix it?

Comment: Do you use Magento default caching only or do you have additional caching, like FPC (Full Page Cache)?

Comment: No i have default cache only

Comment: @Magento2 Did you get you point?